# Android database.sqlite.SQLiteException in Query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I'm new to Android Studio. I am creating a contact manager mobile application. The contacts can be added to my SQLite database and the correct names of contacts are being displayed. When clicked, the name of the contact should appear in another activity. I was using the putExtra method but it would not work. This is my code for the first activity when a name is clicked:

```
    lv_contactlist.setAdapter(aa_contacts);
    lv_contactlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Name = (lv_contactlist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Name",Name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The second activity receives this name and should show the full contact information. This is my code:

```
String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
    Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * contact WHERE NAME = " + Name, null);
    name.setText("NAME: "+cursor.getString(0));
    homephone.setText("HOME PHONE: "+cursor.getString(1));
    mobilephone.setText("MOBILE PHONE: "+cursor.getString(2));
    mobilephone.setText("EMAIL ADDRESS: "+cursor.getString(3));
```

When debugging, I get the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "contact": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * contact WHERE NAME = John
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                (near "contact": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * contact WHERE NAME = John)
```

This is the exact name appearing on my list. This has led me to believe it has to be the putExtra method passing the information to the second activity or the getStringExtra method receiving the name. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong:

instead of:

```
 Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * contact WHERE NAME = " + Name, null);
```

use:

```
 String[] params = new String[]{ Name };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from contact WHERE NAME = ?", params);
```

Comment: This too is wrong, as it does not take into account quoting the value. Use `sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * from contact WHERE NAME = ?", new Object[] { Name });`.

Comment: Thank you but @CommonsWare this is still giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a 'FROM'. It should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column = value.
```

In your case, probably:

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE NAME = John
```

Answer (score 0):

From your attached error `logs`, seem its `SQLITE ERROR`.

```
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(near "contact": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * contact WHERE NAME = John)
```

**Update your SQL Query as below:**

```
String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE NAME = " + Name, null);
```

Hope this will help~